# Perl cmd option for printing first string from a matched line

Tags: perl

I have a text file as input like this:let say it as xyz.txt

```
TIME    SR No               TYPE DATA

2.046103 1  1               Tx   d 8 01 01 01 99 9A 9B 9C 9D
2.046163 3  1               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 99 9A 9B 9C 9D
2.046361 2  1               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 99 9A 9B 9C 9D
2.046916 1  3               Tx   d 8 01 01 01 9B 9C 9D 9E 9F
2.046977 3  3               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 9B 9C 9D 9E 9F
2.047177 2  3               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 9B 9C 9D 9E 9F
2.048034 1  5               Tx   d 8 01 01 01 AD AE AF B0 B1
2.048095 3  5               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 AD AE AF B0 B1
2.048295 2  5               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 AD AE AF B0 B1
2.050006 1  8               Tx   d 8 01 01 01 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
2.050065 3  8               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
2.050265 1  8               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
2.050632 2  601             Rx   d 8 01 01 01 CA CB CC CD CE
2.050690 3  700             Rx   d 8 01 01 01 CA CB CC CD CE
2.050887 1  700             Rx   d 8 01 01 01 CA CB CC CD CE
```

Requirement: I like to extract the first numeric strings (TIME) from lines that contains the SR "1" and TYPE as "Rx"

I hardly know perl and tried a command by reading on internet i.e:

```
perl -nle "print if /"1"\s(.+?)"Rx"/" xyz.txt >>output.txt
```

for extracting matched lines

The output i got in output.txt is:

```
2.046163 3  1               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 99 9A 9B 9C 9D
2.046361 2  1               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 99 9A 9B 9C 9D
2.050265 1  8               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
2.050632 2  601             Rx   d 8 01 01 01 CA CB CC CD CE
2.050887 1  700             Rx   d 8 01 01 01 CA CB CC CD CE
```

Desired output(Requirement) are only these:

```
2.050265              
2.050887
```

The complete information about above two value are from xyz.txt  :

```
2.050265 1  8               Rx   d 8 01 01 01 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
2.050887 1  700             Rx   d 8 01 01 01 CA CB CC CD CE
```

help me....what changes i need to do, so that it will satisfy:

a. consider only "1" from Rx row and not from No row in xyz.txt file.

b. Remove all except first string in output.txt

Comment: Use code tags to format your data and code. Your post is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid regexes as being hard to maintain.

```
perl -lne '@a=split; print "$a[0]" if (($a[1] == 1) and ($a[3] eq "Rx"))'
```

Explanation:

- split -- splits your line into tokens, separated by whitespace.
- print "$a[0]" -- prints the first token
- $a[1] == 1 -- evaluates if the 2nd token evaluates numerically to 1
- $a[3] eq "Rx" -- evaluates if the 4th token equals the string Rx.

Also, the command line switches:

- -l causes perl to process lines similar to awk/sed (ignores leading/trailing whitespace)
- -n causes perl to apply the perl program to each line of input
- -e supplies the perl code to execute on the command line, as the next argument.

Comment: you don't need to split in 1-liners. You can see my answer for an example of using `-a` to do the splitting for you

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -ane '{print "$F[0]\n" if $F[1] == 1 && $F[3] eq "Rx"}' xyz.txt 

2.050265
2.050887
```

Comment: By issuing : perl -ane '{print "$F[0]\n" if $F[1] == 1 && $F[3] eq "Rx"}' xyz.txt as you said shows error Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1. i changed it to perl -ane "{print "$F[0]\n" if $F[1] == 1 && $F[3] eq "Rx"}" xyz.txt as using on windows its showing :error Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "]\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "]\"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
do i have to write a .plx/.pl script for it as you mensioned F[0], F[3] arrays ??

Comment: @user1117568 - that's because on Windows you can't use apostrophe (single quote) as a quote character as you can on Unix. It's not a Perl thing, it's an OS thing. If you want to do it, you need to use double quotes, and then escape all the double-quotes in the code (e.g. `\"$F[0]\n\"`)

Comment: @user1117568 - No, using `-a` creates the @F array for you, that's the beauty. You shoud read [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) if you want to use Perl one-liners effectively

Comment: @user1117568 - feel free to show your appreciation in the usual SO way, by accepting the answer you find helpful (checkmark next to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use groupings in your regular expression to do this:

```
perl -nle 'print $1, "\n" if /^([0-9\.]+) 1\s(.+?)Rx/' xyz.txt >>output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if m/^(\S+)\s1\s.*Rx/' xyz.txt >>output.txt
```